# Can't make a sidebar appear with an Onclick event in react

Tags: reactjs

I am a junior software developer and I am trying to make a sidebar appear when I click a hamburger menu. I wrote a function that toggles my state between true and false, but nothing happens. Please help!! Below is  my code:

```
const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(true)

const toggleSideNav = () => {
    setIsExpanded(!isExpanded)
    console.log(isExpanded)
    
if (isExpanded == false) {
         return <Fragment />
     } else {
         return <SideBar />
     }

useEffect(() => {
    toggleSideNav()
}, [])

}

<button onClick={toggleSideNav}>
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBars} />
</button>
```

When I click the button the state toggles as expected, but nothing else happens.

Comment: Why do you use your toggleSideNav function in useEffect hook? You just need to give it as onClick parameter in your button element.

Comment: Did you pass the function through `onClick` attribute?

Comment: <button onClick={toggleSideNav}>
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBars} />
</button>

Comment: Can you please check your code again? Why is the return condition and useEffect inside the toggleSideNav function?

Comment: The useEffect is not part of the toggle function. I didn't copy the closing brace. I updated the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that if you return the Fragment/Sidebar like that, you won't be able to render the toggle button once the isExpanded is true. You might want to do something like this instead.

```
const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(true)

const toggleSideNav = () => {
    setIsExpanded(prev => !prev)
}

return{
<Fragment>
  {isExpanded && <SideBar />}
  <button onClick={toggleSideNav}>
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBars} />
  </button>
</Fragment>
}
```

By doing this, the Sidebar will only be shown when isExpanded will be true, and the toggle button will be still there to close the Sidebar again